# Swift - NSDictionary optional value crash

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6

```
let dataArray = jsonDict["results"] as NSArray;
for item in dataArray {
    let obj = item as NSDictionary

    var destination:String = obj["destination"] as String!
    println(destination)
}
```

Above I have an NSArray that I am looping through which was obtained by parsing a JSON file.

My problem is, I can see some output where `println` is successful but the application crashes whilst looping through. I'm pretty sure this is because of how I'm handling the NSDictionary optional values but I'm not sure how to get around it.

Do I need to check the optional value or something along those lines before printing it?

Any ideas?

Comment: It's unlikely that the crash is in println. obj ["destination"] probably doesn't exist or isn't a string.

Comment: Do not explicitly unwrap anything unless you are 100% sure that the value can never under any circumstances be nil. Unless you are trying for crashes.

Comment: I have just checked the JSON, there is a small chance one of the objects could have a 'null' value for destination, so not a string, how can I get around this? I am a Swift noob

Comment: @Zaph So I need to check if the value is not nil before unwrapping? Could you please leave an answer showing how to do that?

Comment: What makes you think that `jsonDict` is actually a dictionary and that it contains an entry for key `results` that is an array of dictionaries that each contain a value for key `destination `. Provide a log of `jsonDict `.

Comment: Read the docs. tl;dr does not work for programming.

Comment: Woah hold up, that information is correct otherwise I wouldn't have provided it. The problem is with the destination key and that alone, that is all I am having problems with

Comment: If you are going to use Swift (which I do not recommend) then you are going to have to understand optionals, testing for nil and unwrapping. It is all explained in the Apple Swift docs and several very good blogs.

Comment: @gnasher729 Thanks, that was the reason. I checked the value now and it no longer crashes

Comment: @Zaph I'm curious as to why you don't recommend using swift (seriously, no smarty-pants comment intended)

Comment: @lascort For reasons such as here. Optionals are not an easy subject and to many developers are just throwing in explicit unwrapping "!" when in-appropriate. This made worse by the compiler recommending them! It turns out extracting items from nested dictionaries and arrays such as de-serializing JSON produces is especially fraught with obstacles in Swift. There are many additional reasons that have to do with development best practice such as writing to the interface (there is none) and defaulting class instance methods to being public to the entire module.

Comment: @Zaph I appreciate that comment a lot. You're right, at the moment I am just looking for the easy option. I'll go away and take a deeper look at understanding them properly if I'm to go any further with it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let dataArray = jsonDict["results"] as NSArray;
for item in dataArray {
    let obj = item as NSDictionary

    if let foundName = obj["destination"] {
        println("Name: \(foundName)")
    }
}
```

Checking the optional value before printing it fixed the problem.